# How can I properly restore and use saved Hobby paths?

Tags: tikz-pgf, hobby, tikz-path

The excellent Hobby library's documentation says that it is possible to save and reuse Hobby paths. The examples include paths which are shifted and redrawn with different properties.

However, I cannot figure out how to get my restored paths to behave properly. They seem to get lost when drawing the start or end of the path and to end up in the wrong place.

As I understand it, the red, blue and grey curves should all be identical, with the blue and grey shifted slightly to the left and right of the original red. However, neither the blue nor grey is the same shape as the red, as I believe they should be.

What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass[tikz,12pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path [draw=red] (0,0) coordinate (f) to[curve through={+(.125,-.5) +(-.5,-1) +(0,-1.5) +(.5,-.75) }, save Hobby path={ff1}] (f);
  \path [draw=blue,xshift=1mm] (f) [restore and use Hobby path={ff1}{}];
  \path [draw=gray,xshift=-1.5mm] (f) [restore and use Hobby path={ff1}{}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: wayward Hobby paths]

Comment: The (_already defined_)  position of the `f` coordinate is not modified by the `xshift` operation.

Comment: BTW: how did you obtain such smooth lines in your question? The picture from my answer has 600 or 1200 dpi resolution (PNG) and is of much worse quality.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke It is just how they come out. I just clip them in Okular.

Answer (score 7):

Replacing the absolute `(f)` by the relative `(0,0)` gives the desired result (here also with the variant using `scope`):

```
\documentclass[tikz,12pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%  \path [draw=red] (0,0) coordinate (f) to[curve through={+(.125,-.5) +(-.5,-1) +(0,-1.5) +(.5,-.75) }, save Hobby path={ff1}] (f);
\path [draw=red] (0,0) coordinate (f) to[curve through={+(.125,-.5) +(-.5,-1) +(0,-1.5) +(.5,-.75) }, save Hobby path={ff1}] (f);
\begin{scope}[xshift=+1mm]
%  \path [draw=blue,xshift=1mm] (f) [restore and use Hobby path={ff1}{}];
 \path [draw=blue] (0,0) [restore and use Hobby path={ff1}{}];
 \end{scope} 
  \path [draw=gray,xshift=-1.5mm] (0,0) [restore and use Hobby path={ff1}{}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Just for comparison of the syntax, here's the same diagram written in Hobby's own Metapost...

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[border=10bp]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
  path ff;
  ff = ((0,0) .. (1/8,-1/2) .. (-1/2,-1) .. 
     (0,-3/2) .. (1/2,-3/4) .. (0,0) .. cycle) scaled 28;
  draw ff withcolor red;
  draw ff shifted 3 right withcolor blue;
  draw ff shifted 5 left  withcolor 1/2 white;
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

[image]